# C++ header file (.h) or .h file in C to contain filter coefficients

Tags: c++, c, filtering, header-files

I worked on a DSP project before where filter coefficients (coeffs) are listed in the header file (.h) as a single column. Then somehow it is loaded into a array (named BArray) in C/C++ programming, and operations on these coeffs are done based on this array (BArray). However, I couldn't remember how to load these coeffs in the header file into an array in C/C++. The hardware used is a TI chip.

Comment: Show your header file.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here, since you didn't give a lot of information in the question.

```
double BArray[] = {
#include "coeffs.h"
    };
```